# VueJS error in axios [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.axios.get(...).then(...).cache is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have an error in Vue js that when I use Axios give the error :
***[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.axios.get(...).then(...).cache is not a function"***
I can't get any solution for this problem.

Import Axios from main.js:

```
import * as axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

When I use Axios in components:

```
 this.axios
 .get("https://api.github.com/users/" + this.username + "/repos")
 .then(response => {
      this.repos = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
  })
  .cache(error => {
       this.error = true;
       console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Typo OP... it's 'catch' not 'cache'

Comment: Okay, you are right.